# Getting error and directly open debug manifest.xml while compileing the program not giving the error in same file

Tags: android, debugging, manifest

Getting this type of error don't know whats wrong in this but getting the error and stuck in this..

Every time i run the program gives me the same error and when i click on error it will open this page

```
 E:\OmCom2\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
```

getting error like 
Logcat :-

```
 E:\OmCom2\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(32) No resource identifier found for attribute 'multiDexEnabled' in package 'android'
Error:(32) No resource identifier found for attribute 'multiDexEnabled' in package 'android'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Weal.sachin.omcom"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: you need to add `multiDexEnabled true inside `defaultConfig`

Comment: i did this and it is already there on manifest file and it is giving me error in the debug page itws path like E:\OmCom2\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @PavneetSingh did u get my question?